# Sort Dataframe in R by using 2 different ordering methods

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    well_idx_vector        mass volume neg_control
1               H11 0.009366979    500         0.0
5               H10 0.005421779    500         0.0
9                H9 0.005869947    500         0.0
13               H8 0.004795850    500         0.0
17               H7 0.003171749    500         5.2
21               H6 0.003376679    500         4.6
25               H5 0.002591224    500         0.0
29               H4 0.004296721    500         5.7
33               H3 0.009735851    500         0.0
37               H2 0.005806398    500         8.4
41              G11 0.026943706    500         0.0
45              G10 0.053557516    500         3.0
49               G9 0.053424353    500         0.0
53               G8 0.101048356    500         0.0
57               G7 0.134918211    500         3.0
61               G6 0.154740298    500         0.0
65               G5 0.150639698    500         0.0
69               G4 0.105248793    500         0.0
73               G3 0.056218890    500         0.0
77               G2 0.044184765    500         0.0
81              F11 0.004311336    500         0.0
85              F10 0.003248083    500         0.0
89               F9 0.003612080    500         0.0
93               F8 0.002984221    500         0.0
97               F7 0.002622425    500         0.0
101              F6 0.002755702    500         0.0
105              F5 0.002125027    500         0.0
109              F4 0.003665278    500         0.0
113              F3 0.006419565    500         0.0
117              F2 0.004025916    500         0.0
121             E11 0.008369456    500         0.0
125             E10 0.007690647    500         0.0
129              E9 0.009800190    500         0.0
133              E8 0.026999688    500         0.0
137              E7 0.076243655    500         0.0
141              E6 0.144946547    500         0.0
145              E5 0.162233828    500         6.5
149              E4 0.104610457    500         0.0
153              E3 0.070559076    500         0.0
157              E2 0.067716717    500         0.0
161             D11 0.009099992    500         0.0
165             D10 0.005349740    500         0.0
169              D9 0.006191890    500         0.0
173              D8 0.005861958    500         0.0
177              D7 0.004369067    500         0.0
181              D6 0.004488258    500         0.0
185              D5 0.003315325    500         0.0
189              D4 0.004248404    500         0.0
193              D3 0.004835732    500         0.0
197              D2 0.005240292    500         0.0
201             C11 0.022015707    500         0.0
205             C10 0.013906228    500         0.0
209              C9 0.010194517    500         0.0
213              C8 0.010884621    500         0.0
217              C7 0.012959556    500         4.1
221              C6 0.022814209    500         1.4
225              C5 0.066223146    500        17.5
229              C4 0.037144041    500         0.0
233              C3 0.018543935    500         5.4
237              C2 0.015455041    500         4.9
241             B11 0.004198596    500         0.0
245             B10 0.005485408    500         0.0
249              B9 0.006233599    500         0.0
253              B8 0.012478330    500         0.0
257              B7 0.009894567    500         0.0
261              B6 0.008895920    500         0.0
265              B5 0.013198592    500         0.0
269              B4 0.012333688    500         0.0
273              B3 0.007915466    500         0.0
277              B2 0.008411102    500         0.0
281             A11 0.005488688    500         0.0
285             A10 0.004107467    500         0.0
289              A9 0.006539720    500         0.0
293              A8 0.008039929    500         0.0
297              A7 0.006302248    500         0.0
301              A6 0.006857599    500         0.0
305              A5 0.007671245    500         0.0
309              A4 0.006155090    500         0.0
313              A3 0.005278983    500         0.0
317              A2 0.009681976    500         0.0
```

I need to sort this dataframe by the well_idx_vector column in an order where A comes first, G comes last, and where the well_idx elements that begin with  A,C,E,G are ascending, and those starting with B,D,F,H are descending

(ex: A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,B11,B10,B9,B8,B7,B6,B5,B4,B3,B2,C2,C3 ... ect).

So my question is what is the best way to order this dataframe in a two different ways at the same time? Thank you in advance. I tried using the order() function but was having little luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ind <- data.frame(well_idx_vector=paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each=11), c(1:11, 11:1)), stringsAsFactors=F)
merge(ind, df, by="well_idx_vector", sort=FALSE)
```

The assumption above is that it is realistic to have the general ranges before the operation. `ind` is just an expansion of the expected order. If the data is too large to determine that information, extra steps can be taken to split the id vector into letters and numbers. From there we can extract the relevant information if necessary.

```
#    well_idx_vector        mass volume neg_control
# 1               A2 0.009681976    500         0.0
# 2               A3 0.005278983    500         0.0
# 3               A4 0.006155090    500         0.0
# 4               A5 0.007671245    500         0.0
# 5               A6 0.006857599    500         0.0
# 6               A7 0.006302248    500         0.0
# 7               A8 0.008039929    500         0.0
# 8               A9 0.006539720    500         0.0
# 9              A10 0.004107467    500         0.0
# 10             A11 0.005488688    500         0.0
# 11             B11 0.004198596    500         0.0
# 12             B10 0.005485408    500         0.0
# 13              B9 0.006233599    500         0.0
# 14              B8 0.012478330    500         0.0
# 15              B7 0.009894567    500         0.0
```

Comment: It does work with the sort set to FALSE. I will update.

Comment: I get Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column